# L'Hopital rule for upper and lower limit?

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading the following paper [1998(H.Hudzik)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44152979) P.574

It reads using L'Hopital rule$$\liminf_{u\to\infty} \frac{1/\varphi(1/u)}{\psi(u)}=\liminf_{u\to\infty}\frac{\varphi'(u)}{\psi'(u)u^2[\varphi(1/u)]^2}.$$
That means we can apply L'Hopital for lower limits i.e. $$\liminf_{u\to\infty} \frac{f(u)}{g(u)}=\liminf_{u\to\infty}\frac{f'(u)}{g'(u)}?$$
But I only know the classical one. Is there someone can give me some reference to check this formula? Or if possible someone can give a proof?

Comment: A full proof of L'Hôpital's rule can be found at https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00029890.1952.11988058 .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The full L'Hopital rule says that
$$\liminf \frac{f'}{g'}\leq\liminf\frac{f}{g}\leq\limsup\frac{f}{g}\leq\limsup\frac{f'}{g'}.$$
So in the special case when the limit of $f'/g'$, exists, the limit of $f/g$
also exists and is equal to the limit of $f'/g'$.

This general rule is proved by integration.

Comment: For those interested, a little known paper of William Henry Young, [*On indeterminate forms*](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s2-8.1.40) [**Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society** (2) 8 (1910), pp. 40-76], extended this by proving (among other things) that every subsequential limit point of $f/g$ is a subsequential limit point of $f'/g'.$  In fact, I think Young's paper is the first paper in which even the weaker version involving $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ appears, the weaker version being (I think) rediscovered by [Picone (1929)](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A55.0642.05) **(continued)**

Comment: and [Amante (1936)](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A62.1185.01) and [Halvorsen (1963)](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0119.05601). A nice survey of many subtle versions of L'Hopital's rule is given in: Ioan Muntean, *L'Hôpital's rules with extreme limits* , pp. 11−28 in **Seminar on Mathematical Analysis** (Preprint 93-7), "Babeş-Bolyai" University, Cluj-Napoca, 1993 (MR1333230; [Zbl 833.26007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0833.26007)). Although I have a photocopy of this paper, I cannot find it on the internet. Muntean cites Picone's paper, but not the papers by Young or Amante or Halvorsen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice reference. This is much helpful.

Answer (score 11):

**Q:** Is it true that
$$\liminf_{u\to\infty} \frac{f(u)}{g(u)}\stackrel{?}{=}\liminf_{u\to\infty}\frac{f'(u)}{g'(u)}.$$
**A:** No, try $f(u)=u+\sin u$ and $g(u)=u$, then the left-hand-side of the equation equals 1, while the right-hand-side equals 0. The best you can do is replace = by $\geq$.

Comment: But my confused point why this paper use this rule,  if we want this formula equal, which condition should we consider?

Comment: the equality is correct if $\lim_{u\rightarrow\infty}f'(u)/g'(u)$ exists.